# ¿Por qué no me resetea la función?

Tags: javascript, html5

Me gustaría saber, por qué no me *resetea* la alarma, me refiero a ponerla a cero nuevamente. ¿estaré ocupando mal el *reset*?.

Me gustaría que alguien me pudiera ayudar en el código o que me comentara qué es lo que he hecho mal con la función *reset*.

He visto en varias páginas que lo colocan de esta forma, pero quizás no lo estoy colocando bien:

```js
document.getElementById('programar').addEventListener("click", desaparecer);

function desaparecer() {
  h = parseInt(document.getElementById("horas").value);
  m = parseInt(document.getElementById("minutos").value);
  s = parseInt(document.getElementById("segundos").value);
  document.getElementsByClassName("form")[0].style.animationName = "desaparecer";
  document.getElementsByClassName("form")[0].style.animationDuration = "0.4s";
  document.getElementsByClassName("form")[0].style.animationIterationCount = "1";
  document.getElementsByClassName("form")[0].style.animationFillMode = "forwards";
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("form")[0].style.display = "none";
    aparecer(h, m, s)
  }, 400);
  setInterval(function() {
    aparecer(h, m, s)
  }, 1000);
}

function aparecer(h, m, s) {
  tiempo = calcularTiempo(h, m, s);
  horas = tiempo[0];
  minutos = tiempo[1];
  segundos = tiempo[2];
  document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = horas;
  document.getElementById("m").innerHTML = minutos;
  document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = segundos;
  document.getElementsByClassName("alarma")[0].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName("alarma")[0].style.animationName = "aparecer";
  document.getElementsByClassName("alarma")[0].style.animationDuration = "0.4s";
  document.getElementsByClassName("alarma")[0].style.animationIterationCount = "1";
}


function calcularTiempo(h, m, s) {
  tiempoActual = new Date();
  hs = tiempoActual.getHours();
  ms = tiempoActual.getMinutes();
  ss = tiempoActual.getSeconds();

  total = hs * 3600;
  total += ms * 60;
  total += ss;

  horaAlarma = h * 3600;
  horaAlarma += m * 60;
  horaAlarma += s;

  if (horaAlarma > total) {
    diferencia = horaAlarma - total;
  } else if (horaAlarma == total) {
    document.getElementById("audio").play();
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("¡¡¡¡despertate!!!!")
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    diferencia = horaAlarma + 3600 * 24 - total;
  }
  HorasDif = Math.floor(diferencia / 3600);
  MinutosDif = Math.floor((diferencia - HorasDif * 3600) / 60);
  SegundosDif = Math.floor(diferencia - HorasDif * 3600 - MinutosDif * 60);

  Resultado = HorasDif + ":" + MinutosDif + ":" + SegundosDif;
  return Resultado.split(":");
}


let field1 = document.getElementById('horas');
let field2 = document.getElementById('minutos');
let field3 = document.getElementById('segundos');
let fields = [field1, field2, field3];
field1.focus();
let currentField = 0;


function resetear() {
  document.getElementById("userForm").reset();
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
}

form {
  margin: auto;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  margin-top: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #aaa
}

.alarma {
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  margin-top: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #aaa;
  font-size: 35px;
  border-top: 12px solid #444;
  padding: 18px 10px
}

.alarma div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px
}

form input {
  padding: 9px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}

form input[type="button"] {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff
}

@keyframes desaparecer {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes aparecer {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input class="focusNext" type="number" max="23" min="0" id="horas" tabindex="1" onfocus="changeField(0)">
  <input class="focusNext" type="number" max="59" min="0" id="minutos" tabindex="2" onfocus="changeField(1)">
  <input class="focusNext" type="number" max="59" min="0" id="segundos" tabindex="3" onfocus="changeField(2)">
  <!-- <input class = "focusNext" type="button" id="programar" value="Iniciar" > -->
</form>
<div class="alarma">
  <div class="numeros">
    <div class="active" id="h"></div>
    <div class="puntos">:</div>
    <div id="m"></div>
    <div class="puntos">:</div>
    <div id="s"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="mm">
</div>

<button type="button" id="programar" value="Iniciar">Guardar</button>
<button type="button" id="reset" value="resetear" onclick="resetear">Resetear</button>
```

He estado intentando de esta forma el dar un *reset*, y ponerla otra vez en cero, pero no me funciona.

Comment: El código debe estar dentro de tu pregunta para no depender de sitios externos. Por favor edita la pregunta y añádelo.

Comment: tenias razón, me disculpo por no poner antes el código, pero como veras, he estado intentando de esa forma el dar el reset, pero no me funciona, estaré poniendo mal algo ?

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que no estás capturando bien el formulario en la función resetear. También veo que, en el onclick te faltan los paréntesis para llamar a la función. ¿Has probado a meter los button dentro del form y usar simplemente un button type reset?

Comment: realizare pruebas de lo comentado, también quería probar el cual no es una solución tan agradable en usar: function resetTimer() {
  location.reload();
}
 Bueno refrescar toda la pagina no es una buena opción pensaría, pero esto solo lo realice por prueba.